# Power factor leading and lagging effect on power

Tags: power, power-factor-correction

Why doesn't power factor leading or lagging bring any effect to apparent power? While for reactive power, lagging will result in a positive answer and leading will result in a negative answer?

Answer (score 2):

> *Why does power factor leading or lagging did not bring any effect to
> apparent power ?*

Apparent power is \$V_{RMS}\times I_{RMS}\$ hence, PF does not affect it.

> *While for reactive power, lagging will result in a positive answer and
> leading will result in a negative answer?*

[image: That is incorrect.]

Image above from [wiki power factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor).

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to know what the apparent power is. The apparent power in no way takes into account the phase position of the current in relation to the voltage. It is read and calculated from 2 different measuring devices. The specification of the apparent power alone has as little informative value as, for example, the specification of the screen diagonal for televisions.

The reactive power is the power that is returned to the network as soon as it has been withdrawn from it. For this you need the simultaneous consideration of current and voltage. You have to multiply the voltage value and the current value with each other at every moment. The negative power is the reactive power.

The same applies to the real power, only that the sign of the real power is positive. This means that the product of the voltage and the current is positive at every moment.